# How to set the first option to null in a drupal drop down list?

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7

A drop list is generated from a database, and the first option is always selected. How can I set the first option blank and display the message "Select option" in the first option? This is my source code:

```
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('asset_type');
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary->vid);
foreach ($tree as $item) {
    $options[$item->name] = str_repeat('-', $item->depth) . $item->name;
}
$form['search_fieldset']['doc_type']=array( '#type'=>'select', '#title'=>
    t('Document Type'),'#options' => $options, );
```

Comment: below is code

 $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('asset_type');
 $tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary->vid);
 foreach ($tree as $item) {
    $options[$item->name] = str_repeat('-', $item->depth) . $item->name;
 }
  $form['search_fieldset']['doc_type']=array(
        '#type'=>'select',
        '#title'=>t('Document Type'),
  '#options' => $options,
    );

Comment: Please make sure your source code is displayed in the question correctly. A simple guide can be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('asset_type');
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary->vid);
foreach ($tree as $item) {
    $options[$item->name] = str_repeat('-', $item->depth) . $item->name;
}

array_unshift($options, array("-" => "Select option"));

$form['search_fieldset']['doc_type']=array( '#type'=>'select', '#title'=>
    t('Document Type'),'#options' => $options, );
```

Notice the array_unshift function which insert the desired option at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

"#empty_option"=>t('- Select -'),